# Inverse transform of $\int K(s,t) \rho(s) dS $

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, integral-transforms

Assume that $V$ is a n-dimensional surface, or the disjoint union such surfaces.
Let $K(s,t)$ be a function $V^2\to \mathbb R$. For the sake of simplicity, it can be assumed that $K$ is continuous, differentiable etc.

We assume furthermore that for every differentiable function $\rho: V \to \mathbb R$, integrable on $V$, the relation $$\int_V K(s,t) \rho(s) dS(s) = 0 $$ holds for all $t$ if and only if $\rho = 0$ identically.
This means that the transform $F$ defined by
$$F(\rho)(t) = \int_V K(s,t)\rho(s) dS(s)$$
is 1-1.

Under these conditions, I have some reasons (see below) to believe that $F$ is invertible, with invert of the form $$F^{-1}(\rho)(s) = \int_V K'(s,t)\rho(t) dS(t),$$
where $K':V^2\to \mathbb R$.

What work has been done in this direction? Is there an available general theorem?

**Motivation**: Let us divide the surface $V$ into a finite number $n$ of small patches $S_i$.
Then approximately,
$$F(\rho)(t) = \int_V K(s,t)\rho(s) dS(s) = \sum_i K(s_i,t) \rho(s_i) S_i,$$
where $s_i$ is centered at $S_i$.  Writing $x_i = \rho(s_i) S_i$, we see that For every $t$, we have a linear relation of the form $$F(\rho)(t) = \sum_i K(s_i, t) x_i.$$
In particular, choosing $t = s_j$, we have for every $j\in \{1,\ldots n\}$
$$F(\rho)(s_j) = \sum_i K(s_i, s_j) x_i.$$
This is a system of $n$ equations in $n$ variables $x_i$,
where $K(s_i, s_j)$ can be viewed as a square matrix.
Because $F$ is 1-1, it should be true that $K(s_i, s_j)$ is invertible, hence we have
$$x_i = \sum_j K^{-1}(s_i, s_j) F(\rho)(s_j).$$
But since $x_i = \rho(s_i)S_i$ is "very small" (infinitesimal of order 1) while $F(\rho)(s_j)$ is finite, $K^{-1}$ must be very very small (infinitesimal of order 2), of the form
$$(K'(s_i, s_j) S_i S_j)_{i,j},$$ with $K'$ a finite matrix.
Hence we "can" rewrite the previous equation as
$$\rho(s_i) = \sum_i K'(s_i, s_j) F(\rho)(s_j)S_j.$$
Switching to the continuum, this would amount to:
$$\rho(s) = \int_V K'(s, t) F(\rho)(t) dS(t).$$
Well, that's very very informal of course, but this makes sense.

Comment: The inverse must be an unbounded operator, hopefully densely defined. Actually, since $K$ is continuous, $F$ is a compact operatpr (all called a completely continuous operator ?) over $C(V)$.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a full answer but something for the special case where $V$ is a domain in $\mathbb{R}^d$. Such integral operators
$$
F\rho(t) = \int_V K(s,t)\rho(s)ds
$$
are usually compact: If $K\in L^2(V\times V)$, then $F$ is linear and bounded from $L^2(V)$ into itself and also compact. Consequently, the singular values of $F$ go to zero and hence, no continuous inverse exist and on top of that the Moore-Penrose pseudo-inverse is bounded only if the range of $F$ is of finite dimension.

To comment on your approach to invertibility: The matrices you get will be badly conditioned (i.e. have large and small singular values) and the condition number will diverge to infinity when you discretize finer and finer.

Comment: Thank you for answering me. My knowledge is limited in this domain, and I lost you when you said "Consequently, the singular values of F go to zero and hence, no continuous inverse exist". Could you elaborate a bit in your answer? Regarding my motivating pseudo-demonstration, I am of course aware that it is not viable, even as an "approach" to this problem; it was just "kind of" informal approach.

Comment: Note: I'm not sure what you mean by "domain in $\mathbb R^d$". In my setting, $V$ is a surface in $\mathbb R^d$ or the union of disjoint surfaces. I meant a  differentiable manifold of dim d-1, or the union of such manifolds. To fix my ideas, I was considering objects like spheres, ellipsoids etc. in $\mathbb R^3$.

Comment: A compact operator on a Hilbert space has a singular value decomposition which can be obtained by application of the spectral theorem for compact and self-adjoint operators to the operator $F^*F$. This may be found in books on functional analysis (while most treat the spectral theorem, not all treat the singular value decomposition). A domain in R^d is just an open and connected subset of R^d. It may be that everything is the same if $V$ is a surface, but I haven't thought about it.